# How do I visit ipv4 addresses (not domain) from an ipv6-only network?

Tags: networking, ipv6, ipv4

I got an ipv6-only server and I want to visit ipv4 addresses like 8.8.8.8 with it. I know that I can visit ipv4-only website through DNS64 and NAT64. However, if the destination is just an ipv4 address like 8.8.8.8 it won't be converted to ipv6 addresses. In this case, how should I configure to visit destinations like 8.8.8.8? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you'll still need NAT64 to do the translation.

Because the destination is an IP address and not a domain name, DNS isn't involved so DNS64 can't convert it to the correct IPv6 address. You'll need an IPv6 address to connect to though.

This means your system needs some other way to do the conversion. This is called 464XLAT. For Linux you can find an implementation here: https://github.com/toreanderson/clatd

Answer (score 3):

In the specific use case of DNS, use IPv6 instead of IPv4. Find your DNS service's IPv6 addresses, get a better DNS with v6 transport, or run your own DNS servers on v6 only.

[Google public DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using) is

- 2001:4860:4860::8888
- 2001:4860:4860::8844

[Cloudflare public DNS](https://developers.cloudflare.com/1.1.1.1/setting-up-1.1.1.1/router) is

- 2606:4700:4700::1111
- 2606:4700:4700::1001

[Quad9 public DNS](https://www.quad9.net/service/service-addresses-and-features) is

- 2620:fe::fe
- 2620:fe::9

[OpenDNS](https://www.opendns.com/about/innovations/ipv6/) is

- 2620:119:35::35
- 2620:119:53::53

Answer (score 0):

I guess this solves your problem

dns64.cloudflare-dns.com (/dns-query)

2606:4700:4700::64
2606:4700:4700::6400

Expanded
2606:4700:4700:0:0:0:0:64

Above is DNS64 for IPv6 only network , providing access to IPv4 using AAAA DNS record , NAT64